# Why is my npm install failing on my ubuntu server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I've encountered an error on my production server when using `npm install` - the build process fails with the following error:

```
npm WARN package.json app@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json app@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json app@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json re-require@0.0.1 No repository field.
/
> phantomjs@1.9.17 install /src/frontend/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Download already available at /src/frontend/node_modules/phantomjs/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /src/frontend/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /src/frontend/node_modules/phantomjs/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1434596446001/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64 -> /src/frontend/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /src/frontend/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser requires debug@'0.7.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/jshint requires lodash@'3.7.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.9.3
npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/karma-browserify/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify requires 

through2@'^1.0.0' but will load
    npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/karma-browserify/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/through2,
    npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.5
    npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify requires through2@'^1.0.0' but will load
    npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/through2,
    npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
    npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify requires xtend@'^3.0.0' but will load
    npm WARN unmet dependency /src/frontend/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/xtend,
    npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.0
    bower-resolve@2.2.1 node_modules/bower-resolve
    └── bower@1.4.1 (is-root@1.0.0, junk@1.0.1, stringify-object@1.0.1, user-home@1.1.1, chmodr@0.1.0, rimraf@2.4.0, abbrev@1.0.7, archy@1.0.0, opn@1.0.2, bower-logger@0.2.2, bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2, graceful-fs@3.0.8, lru-cache@2.6.4, lockfile@1.0.1, nopt@3.0.2, retry@0.6.1, tmp@0.0.24, request-progress@0.3.1, q@1.4.1, chalk@1.0.0, which@1.1.1, shell-quote@1.4.3, bower-json@0.4.0, semver@2.3.2, fstream@1.0.6, p-throttler@0.1.1, promptly@0.2.0, mkdirp@0.5.0, glob@4.5.3, fstream-ignore@1.0.2, insight@0.5.3, tar-fs@1.5.1, update-notifier@0.3.2, decompress-zip@0.1.0, configstore@0.3.2, request@2.53.0, bower-registry-client@0.3.0, github@0.2.4, cardinal@0.4.4, mout@0.11.0, bower-config@0.6.1, handlebars@2.0.0, inquirer@0.8.0)

    Error: Cannot find module 'module-deps'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/src/frontend/node_modules/browserify/index.js:1:75)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

The weird part is that on an identical staging server, with the same package.json, the process goes through fine. How can I debug this type of problem? My package.json is as follows:

```
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower-resolve": "git+https://YPCrumble@github.com/YPCrumble/bower-resolve.git",
    "browser-sync": "^2.7.11",
    "browserify": "^10.2.4",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.9",
    "browserify-transform-tools": "^1.3.0",
    "del": "1.2.0",
    "envify": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-jshint": "1.11.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-minify-css": "1.1.6",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-react-helpers": "^0.2.2",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-browserify": "^4.2.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "0.2.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^0.1.1",
    "less-plugin-clean-css": "^1.5.0",
    "lodash": "^3.3.0",
    "re-require": "0.0.1",
    "react": "0.12.2",
    "react-tools": "^0.12.2",
    "reactify": "1.0.0",
    "sinon": "^1.12.2",
    "vinyl-buffer": "1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^2.4.0"
  },  
"paths": {
    "frontend": "./*.js",
    "less": "./less/*.less",
    "js": "./src/**/*.js",
    "lint": "./*.js",
    "jsx": "./src/**/*.jsx",
    "app": "./app.js",
    "vendor": "./vendor.js",
    "html": "../templates/*.html",
    "python": "../**/*.py"
  },
  "dest": {
    "style": "style.css",
    "app": "app.js",
    "vendor": "vendor.js",
    "dist": "dist"
  },  
  "author": "", 
  "license": "ISC",
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "bootstrap": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ],
      "exports": "bootstrap"
    },
    "jquery-cookie": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ]
    },
 "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery",
        "moment:moment",
        "bootstrap:bootstrap"
      ],
      "exports": "$.fn.datetimepicker"
    },
    "image-picker": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ],
      "exports": "$.fn.imagepicker"
    },
    "raven-js": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ],
      "exports": "raven-js"
    },
    "parsleyjs": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ],
      "exports": "parsleyjs"
    }
  },
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "jquery-cookie": "./bower_components/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js",
    "image-picker": "./bower_components/image-picker/image-picker/image-picker.js",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "./bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
    "moment": "./bower_components/moment/moment.js",
    "bootstrap": "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "raven-js": "./bower_components/raven-js/dist/raven.js",
    "parsleyjs": "./bower_components/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue in the folowing manner:

1. I knew the problem is in npm
2. Update Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. [Completely remove npm and all installed packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm)
4. Reinstall npm
5. At this point, using `npm install` worked as expected.

I'm not really sure of a better way to achieve this result, but there was clearly some kind of bug lurking in my npm installation that debugging would have taken longer than doing this reset.